# VS Code - The git repository at 'c:\Users\myname' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, stack-overflow

I have recently installed Git and my only issue is every time I open VScode it will attempt to give me the warning/error message

```
The git repository at 'c:\Users\myname' has too many active changes, 
only a subset of Git features will be enabled**.
```

There is a listing for over 5000 files. I assume this has something to do with being in the program files folder?

I am new to programming and not sure what the issue is. I checked the other form answers for this question but nothing was making sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have a hidden `.git` folder under `%USERPROFILE%` (your `C:\Users\MyName` folder)

If you do, rename or delete it: there should not be a Git repository for the all Windows HOME folder: that would force VSCode to monitor too many files, as the warning suggests.

Answer (score 0):

probably late but the Git extension offers

> Git: Ignored Repositories

List of git repositories to ignore.

just click add an item and add this path `C:\Users\MyName`

[image: Example]

**Note:** renaming .git folder as [Vonc's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64273952/8348141) is a working solution but it may break other things ( for example: yarn needs a repo in this path and I don't know why)